# Minicart doesn't show any products on homepage

Tags: magento2.3, mini-cart

Somehow, the cart is empty in homepage even when I add the products. Cart display all the content on all the other pages.

I have the theme to default luma theme (we have extended the luma theme) then the minicart shows the added items. Why the cart isn't showing the products while apply the extended theme?

[image]

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: As it is your custom theme, could it be accidentally hiding elements in CSS/Less file?

Comment: @Korbin, I don't know about this. How to check that?

Comment: use your browser console, inspect the minicart element or its content.

Comment: I have checked CSS file and we haven't done anything related to cart on the home page. It seems different issue.

Comment: are you getting any log?

Comment: I have checked and see the below thing in log: Model/Cart.php on line 426 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/procure/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart.php on line 426 at /var/www/html/procure/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"}